# create sparse matrix from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have a data of list of tuples like below:

```
data = [(18, 53), (42, 78),..., (132, 38)]
```

First and second number of tuple represent the ids of row and column, respectively.

Using this data, I want to create a matrix with specific shape `(200, 150)`. (The row and column ids are smaller than the numbers of wanted shape)

The element of matrix is 1 if (i,j) is in the list. (i.e. (18,53)=1,(42, 78)=1,...,(132, 38)=1)

Can someone help me to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work? "Can someone do this for me" is off-topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution to your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

dim_x = 200
dim_y = 150
data = [(18, 53), (42, 78), (132, 38)]
a = np.zeros((dim_x, dim_y), dtype = int)

for el in data:
    if el[0] < dim_x and el[1] < dim_y:
        a[el[0], el[1]] = 1
    
print(a)
```

I'm not going to copy here the output because is huge but I tested it and seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the solution

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
alist = [(18, 53), (42, 78), (132, 38)]

i, j, data = zip(*((i, t, t) for i, row in enumerate(alist) for t in row))


print(csr_matrix((data, (i, j)), shape=(200, 150)).todense())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

data = [(18, 53), (42, 78), (132, 38)]
rows, cols = zip(*data)

res = coo_matrix((np.ones(len(data)), (rows, cols)), shape=(133, 79))

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  (18, 53)  1.0
  (42, 78)  1.0
  (132, 38) 1.0
```

The intended usage is fast matrix construction, from the documentation:

> COO is a fast format for constructing sparse matrices